Grouping functions together in javascript
I'm trying to group functions together in javascript, though I have some difficulty understanding how to keep track of the groups. In the below example, my question is: How does: "some.get('anotherContent')" knows that it's queried under alias "anotherSomeSome" and not "anotherSome"  - What I mean is, how to keep the track of the different aliases in this model? Below is what I have tried, but I find it quiet complex and hard to keep track of the aliases:
class someClass {
    alias(callback) {
        callback();
        return this;
    }

    get(content) {
        return 'some' + content;
    }
}

const some = new someClass();

some.alias('some', () => {
    some.alias('anotherSome', () => {
        some.get('content')
    })
    
    some.get('contents')

    some.alias('anotherSomeSome', () {
        some.get('anotherContent')
    })
})


Does alias take one parameter or two? And what purpose do you intend it to serve?

Your some.alias() function is defined as taking one parameter, but your code passes it two parameters.

why you using classes?

On the surface it looks like an XY problem... Anyway.
A simple approach would be argument drilling, thus you pass your alias down the stack with arguments.
If your code sync you could save your alias in a class property. In my case I save it in path array so the whole stack would be traceable.


class someClass {
    path = [];
    alias(alias, callback) {
        this.path.push(alias);
        callback();
        this.path.pop();
        return this;
    }

    get(content) {
        console.log(this.path.join(' / '), 'some' + content);
    }
}

const some = new someClass();

some.alias('some', () => {
    some.alias('anotherSome', () => {
        some.get('content')
    })
    
    some.get('contents')

    some.alias('anotherSomeSome', () => {
        some.get('anotherContent')
    })
})



As soon as you introduce async (and probably more complex) code you need to track your calls.
I find it interesting to use a proxy that returns some instance with individual path:


class someClass {
    path = [];
    alias(alias, callback) {
        callback(new Proxy(this, {
          get(self, prop){
            if(prop === 'path'){
              return [...self.path, alias];
            }
            return Reflect.get(...arguments);
          }
        }));
        return this;
    }

    get(content) {
        console.log(this.path.join(' / '), 'some' + content);
    }
}

const some = new someClass();

some.alias('some', some => {
    some.alias('anotherSome', some => {
        some.get('content')
    })
    
    some.get('contents')

    some.alias('anotherSomeSome', some => {
        some.get('anotherContent')
    })
})




This is indeed very interesting. Didn't know it was possible to intercept via proxy. Thank u so much
